# Como unir tres tablas con IDs que tiene la tabla principal

Tags: php, mysql, tablas

¡¡¡Hola Comunidad!!!

Tengo el siguiente problema:

***Uso MYSQL***

Quiero unir tres tablas con todos sus columnas. Tengo una tabla principal donde están almacenados dos IDs que hacen referencia a otras dos tablas.

Les adjunto imagen de las tablas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ven la tabla principal es EVENTOS, ahí almaceno a el cliente y vehículo y con esa información quiero consultar los datos del cliente y vehículo con los respectivo IDs que esta almacenados en la tabla, pero también donde el id de eventos es tal.

Adjunto imagen de mi lógica:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por el momento, ya puedo consultar su información de esta manera:

```
SET @ID_Cliente = (SELECT EV_Id_Cliente FROM eventos WHERE id = 55);
SET @ID_Vehiculo = (SELECT EV_Id_Vehiculo FROM eventos WHERE id = 55);

SELECT * FROM eventos WHERE id = 55;
SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE CL_Id_Cliente = @ID_Cliente;
SELECT * FROM vehiculos WHERE VH_Id_Vehiculo = @ID_Vehiculo;
```

Me funciona porque ya tengo sus datos pero quiero unirlos y lograr que queden como si fuera una tabla para poder procesar sus datos en PHP.

Adjunto imagen del resultado esperado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero y me puedan ayudar, he visto las maneras en como se pueden unir las tablas pero no me queda claro cual de ellas me pueda servir.

Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Usa inner join pero antes debes haber echo la relación entre tablas en tu base de datos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La consulta que uniría las tres tablas sería esta:

```
SELECT * FROM eventos e
    INNER JOIN clientes  c ON e.EV_Id_Cliente  = c.CL_Id_Cliente
    INNER JOIN vehiculos v ON e.EV_Id_Vehiculo = v.VH_Id_Vehiculo
WHERE e.id = 55;
```

Como podrás analizar, en los `INNER JOIN` indicas de un lado la columna de la tabla `eventos`, cuyo alias es `e` y del otro la columna de otra tabla (`clientes` cuyo alias es `c` y `vehiculos` cuyo alias es `v`).

Ten en cuenta que hay varios tipos de `JOIN`, ya eso podrás estudiarlo a nivel de SQL, pues algunas veces en vez de `INNER JOIN` te puede convenir un `LEFT JOIN` por ejemplo u otro tipo de `JOIN`.

Generalmente, en este tipo de consultas, para evitar verbosidad (consultas demasiado largas) y confusiones, se suelen usar alias cortos para cada tabla, que generalmente son la primera o dos primeras letras de cada tabla. Luego, pones el alias en cada columna, como hemos hecho aquí en el `WHERE`.

Otro consejo es que en vez de `SELECT *` hagas un `SELECT` únicamente con las columnas que vayas a necesitar. Al hacerlo, podrás el alias de la tabla respectiva delante de cada columna, por ejemplo:

```
SELECT 
    e.id,
    e.title,
    c.CL_nombre,
    v.VH_Marca
FROM eventos e
    INNER JOIN clientes  c ON e.EV_Id_Cliente  = c.CL_Id_Cliente
    INNER JOIN vehiculos v ON e.EV_Id_Vehiculo = v.VH_Id_Vehiculo
WHERE e.id = 55;
```

### Post-Data

En tu tabla `vehiculos` se observa una columna llamada `VH_Id_Cliente` que no tendría sentido, si la pusiste con la intención de relacionarla con la tabla `clientes`, eso significaría que entre cliente y vehículo habría una relación *uno a uno* (un vehículo pertenecería a un solo cliente). Parece que la relación correcta es muchos a muchos, y esa relación queda expresa en la tabla eventos. La consulta de mi respuesta está basada en esa relación por lo que `VH_Id_Cliente` sobraría.